# Get HTML ID in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP and I am wondering if I can access an ID inside HTML and do some editing?

Inside my html file, I have this:

`<div id="Msg" class="message"></div>`

and normally I would edit the text on the client side in javascript using the following:

```
document.getElementById('Msg').innerHTML = '<font color="red">Some text...</font>';
```

Can something like this be done on the server side with PHP? I would like to alter the element before I render the page.  If so, what should I use to access the ID and edit the elements?

Comment: You could do it on the server conditionally. i.e. `if statement`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP DOM Extension.

See [documentation on extension](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php) or direct link [getElementById](http://php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.getelementbyid.php)

But, it's backend processing.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean altering the HTML via PHP after it's been rendered in the user's browser, that can't be done.

1. PHP is server-side, which means it runs on a machine different from the user.
2. Javascript and HTML are client-side, which means they run on the user's machine.
3. The server should have no control over anything on the user's machine.

Therefore, accessing the ID from PHP is not possible. :)

You've got to stick with Javascript, which only runs client-side.

If you want to alter the HTML structure *before* you send to the client, that's possible using the DOM, as @DmitryBergstein points out in his answer.

If you need to access something on the server after the page has been rendered, you need to make an [ajax request](http://www.openjs.com/ajax/tutorial/), then alter the DOM using Javascript after the request has returned some data.

Comment: Thanks, I should've pointed out that I want to alter it before I render it

Comment: Ah, well then @DmitryBergstein's answer is a better fit then (probably deserves the accept ;) ).

Answer (score 1):

PHP generates HTML *before* sending it to the client.

You need to figure out where in the PHP this HTML is being generated.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to update an innerHTML content with PHP once the page is fully loaded, you should have a php script that returns an updated value. Then, you call this script and update your page according to the response. It can be done nicely with an ajax call.

Answer (score -1):

```
$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Msg"]);
```